# HTML multi group select box re-centering the frame around current selection when selecting specific option

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have used HTML multi-group selectbox as below code snippet shown. 
Refer following fiddler for the code
https://jsfiddle.net/nsandaruwa/tj1f2gyx/18/

When selecting a specific option in the select box.since I have used scrollIntoView function, the frame is recentering on the current selection. This behavior is annoying for the user when it comes to user experience.
I want this multi-group select box tobe no scroll when selecting specific option.

is there any function to achieve this behavior?

**HTML:**

```
<select multiple="" class="form-control select-checkbox" size="5">
<optgroup label="One">
  <option>Dog</option>
  <option>Cat</option>
  <option>Hippo</option>
  <option>Dinosaur</option>
  <option>Another Dog</option>
</optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Two">
  <option>Dog</option>
  <option>Cat</option>
  <option>Hippo</option>
  <option>Dinosaur</option>
  <option>Another Dog</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="Three">
  <option>Dog</option>
  <option>Cat</option>
  <option>Hippo</option>
  <option>Dinosaur</option>
  <option>Another Dog</option>
</optgroup>
</select>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
  padding: 15px;
}

.select-checkbox option::before {
  content: "\2610";
  width: 1.3em;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}
.select-checkbox option:checked::before {
  content: "\2611";
}
```

**Jquery:**

```
$('option').mousedown(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const that = this;
    $(this).prop('selected', $(this).prop('selected') ? false : true);
    setTimeout(function() { that.scrollIntoView() },10)
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('option').mousedown(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var originalScrollTop = $(this).parent().parent().scrollTop();
    $(this).prop('selected', $(this).prop('selected') ? false : true);
    var self = this;
    $(this).parent().parent().focus();
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(self).parent().parent().scrollTop(originalScrollTop);
    }, 0);

    return false;
});
```

Fiddle URL for the solution
https://jsfiddle.net/nsandaruwa/0sphnk5z/1/